# How to version a Meteor application with consideration for Mongo

Tags: git, mongodb, meteor, version-control

I'm at a point in a project where we'd like to divert a fair bit and want to branch to test a new DB schema.

Short of firing up a new Mongo database, is there a nice way to get new collections or collection changes into our repo (Git) so switching is as easy as `git checkout`ing a branch?

Answer (score 1):

The git repo would be able to track change in your schema *design*, but not the actual data in your collections.

To track changes in the collection, you would need to fire up another database.  I'd recommend doing something like a [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) if you've taken the time to enter / collect a lot of data.

I'm sure you've seen the pattern before, but the data could then be loaded in a startup function on the server:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  if (Collection.find().count() === 0) {
    console.log("Importing private/collection.json to db")

    //grabs data from exported json file
    var data = JSON.parse(Assets.getText("collection.json"));

    //adds it to your collections
    data.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
      Collection.insert(item);
    })
  }
});
```